# How to Parse JSON object in SWIFT properly

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have tried to parse this JSON object but it's not working.. I'm not getting an error message either.

What I'm trying to do is fetch recipe details from an API to an array but I'm unable to make it work. I can see from the console that the API call has been successful and able to print the json file.

See below the json file, object class & the parse code.

Json file

```
    {
  "recipes" : [
    {
      "veryHealthy" : false,
      "preparationMinutes" : 20,
      "vegan" : false,
      "aggregateLikes" : 8,
      "veryPopular" : false,
      "imageType" : "jpg",
      "diets" : [
        "lacto ovo vegetarian"
      ],
      "creditsText" : "BBC Good Food",
      "extendedIngredients" : [
        {
          "originalString" : "200g unsalted butter, softened",
          "name" : "unsalted butter",
          "measures" : {
            "metric" : {
              "amount" : 200,
              "unitLong" : "grams",
              "unitShort" : "g"
            },
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "ounces",
              "amount" : 7.0549999999999997,
              "unitShort" : "oz"
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
          "meta" : [
            "unsalted",
            "softened"
          ],
          "image" : "butter-sliced.jpg",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "unsalted",
            "softened"
          ],
          "original" : "200g unsalted butter, softened",
          "amount" : 200,
          "originalName" : "unsalted butter, softened",
          "unit" : "g",
          "id" : 1145
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "125g soft brown sugar",
          "name" : "brown sugar",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "ounces",
              "unitShort" : "oz",
              "amount" : 4.4089999999999998
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "grams",
              "unitShort" : "g",
              "amount" : 125
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Baking",
          "meta" : [
            "soft"
          ],
          "image" : "dark-brown-sugar.png",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "soft"
          ],
          "original" : "125g soft brown sugar",
          "amount" : 125,
          "originalName" : "soft brown sugar",
          "unit" : "g",
          "id" : 19334
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "1 tsp ground cinnamon",
          "name" : "ground cinnamon",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "teaspoon",
              "unitShort" : "tsp",
              "amount" : 1
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "teaspoon",
              "unitShort" : "tsp",
              "amount" : 1
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Spices and Seasonings",
          "meta" : [

          ],
          "image" : "cinnamon.jpg",
          "metaInformation" : [

          ],
          "original" : "1 tsp ground cinnamon",
          "amount" : 1,
          "originalName" : "ground cinnamon",
          "unit" : "tsp",
          "id" : 1012010
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "1½ tsp vanilla bean paste",
          "name" : "vanilla bean paste",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "teaspoons",
              "unitShort" : "tsps",
              "amount" : 1.5
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "teaspoons",
              "unitShort" : "tsps",
              "amount" : 1.5
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Gourmet",
          "meta" : [

          ],
          "image" : "molasses.jpg",
          "metaInformation" : [

          ],
          "original" : "1½ tsp vanilla bean paste",
          "amount" : 1.5,
          "originalName" : "vanilla bean paste",
          "unit" : "tsp",
          "id" : 93813
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "1 pineapple, peeled, cut into quarters, core removed, then cut into 2cm slices",
          "name" : "pineapple",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "",
              "unitShort" : "",
              "amount" : 1
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitShort" : "",
              "unitLong" : "",
              "amount" : 1
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Produce",
          "meta" : [
            "peeled",
            "cut into quarters, core removed, then cut into 2cm slices"
          ],
          "image" : "pineapple.jpg",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "peeled",
            "cut into quarters, core removed, then cut into 2cm slices"
          ],
          "original" : "1 pineapple, peeled, cut into quarters, core removed, then cut into 2cm slices",
          "amount" : 1,
          "originalName" : "pineapple, peeled, cut into quarters, core removed, then cut into 2cm slices",
          "unit" : "",
          "id" : 9266
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "140g golden caster sugar",
          "name" : "golden brown sugar",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitShort" : "oz",
              "unitLong" : "ounces",
              "amount" : 4.9379999999999997
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "grams",
              "unitShort" : "g",
              "amount" : 140
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Baking",
          "meta" : [

          ],
          "image" : "dark-brown-sugar.png",
          "metaInformation" : [

          ],
          "original" : "140g golden caster sugar",
          "amount" : 140,
          "originalName" : "golden caster sugar",
          "unit" : "g",
          "id" : 19334
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "2 large eggs, plus 1 egg white, beaten",
          "name" : "eggs",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "larges",
              "unitShort" : "large",
              "amount" : 2
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitShort" : "large",
              "amount" : 2,
              "unitLong" : "larges"
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
          "meta" : [
            "beaten"
          ],
          "image" : "egg.png",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "beaten"
          ],
          "original" : "2 large eggs, plus 1 egg white, beaten",
          "amount" : 2,
          "originalName" : "eggs, plus 1 egg white, beaten",
          "unit" : "large",
          "id" : 1123
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "1½ tsp baking powder",
          "name" : "baking powder",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitShort" : "tsps",
              "amount" : 1.5,
              "unitLong" : "teaspoons"
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "teaspoons",
              "unitShort" : "tsps",
              "amount" : 1.5
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Baking",
          "meta" : [

          ],
          "image" : "white-powder.jpg",
          "metaInformation" : [

          ],
          "original" : "1½ tsp baking powder",
          "amount" : 1.5,
          "originalName" : "baking powder",
          "unit" : "tsp",
          "id" : 18371
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "200g plain flour",
          "name" : "plain flour",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "ounces",
              "unitShort" : "oz",
              "amount" : 7.0549999999999997
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "grams",
              "unitShort" : "g",
              "amount" : 200
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "solid",
          "aisle" : "Baking",
          "meta" : [
            "plain"
          ],
          "image" : "flour.png",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "plain"
          ],
          "original" : "200g plain flour",
          "amount" : 200,
          "originalName" : "plain flour",
          "unit" : "g",
          "id" : 20081
        },
        {
          "originalString" : "75ml whole milk",
          "name" : "whole milk",
          "measures" : {
            "us" : {
              "unitLong" : "fl. ozs",
              "unitShort" : "fl. oz",
              "amount" : 2.536
            },
            "metric" : {
              "unitLong" : "milliliters",
              "unitShort" : "ml",
              "amount" : 75
            }
          },
          "consitency" : "liquid",
          "aisle" : "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
          "meta" : [
            "whole"
          ],
          "image" : "milk.png",
          "metaInformation" : [
            "whole"
          ],
          "original" : "75ml whole milk",
          "amount" : 75,
          "originalName" : "whole milk",
          "unit" : "ml",
          "id" : 1077
        }
      ],
      "cuisines" : [

      ],
      "cheap" : false,
      "ketogenic" : false,
      "sourceUrl" : "https:\/\/www.bbcgoodfood.com\/recipes\/cinnamon-pineapple-upside-down-cake",
      "sustainable" : false,
      "healthScore" : 5,
      "weightWatcherSmartPoints" : 20,
      "sourceName" : "BBC Good Food",
      "whole30" : false,
      "instructions" : "Heat oven to 180C\/160C fan\/gas 4. Put 4 tbsp of the butter into a 22cm springform cake tin and place in the oven to melt. Remove and stir in the brown sugar, cinnamon and  tsp of the vanilla paste. Arrange the pineapple in the buttery sugar mixture, tossing a little to coat. Try to fill all the gaps, so you cant see much of the base.\nIn a mixing bowl, beat the caster sugar and remaining butter using an electric hand whisk for 2-3 mins until light and fluffy. Add the eggs and egg white, one at a time, and the remaining vanilla. Add the baking powder and a pinch of salt, then the flour and milk, beating until they are both incorporated. Beat for 1 min more until smooth.\nSpoon the batter into the pan over the pineapple. Bake for 1 hr, covering with foil if it starts to brown. Leave to rest for 5 mins, then turn out onto a platter and serve warm as a pudding, with crme frache, if you like. Alternatively, leave to cool completely in the tin and serve as a cake.",
      "analyzedInstructions" : [
        {
          "steps" : [
            {
              "ingredients" : [

              ],
              "number" : 1,
              "step" : "Heat oven to 180C\/160C fan\/gas",
              "equipment" : [
                {
                  "name" : "oven",
                  "id" : 404784,
                  "image" : "oven.jpg",
                  "temperature" : {
                    "unit" : "Celsius",
                    "number" : 180
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "ingredients" : [

              ],
              "number" : 2,
              "step" : "Put 4 tbsp of the butter into a 22cm springform cake tin and place in the oven to melt.",
              "equipment" : [
                {
                  "id" : 404747,
                  "image" : "cake-pan.png",
                  "name" : "cake form"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 404784,
                  "image" : "oven.jpg",
                  "name" : "oven"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "ingredients" : [
                {
                  "id" : 93813,
                  "image" : "molasses.jpg",
                  "name" : "vanilla paste"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 19334,
                  "image" : "dark-brown-sugar.png",
                  "name" : "brown sugar"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 9266,
                  "image" : "pineapple.jpg",
                  "name" : "pineapple"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 2010,
                  "image" : "cinnamon.jpg",
                  "name" : "cinnamon"
                }
              ],
              "number" : 3,
              "step" : "Remove and stir in the brown sugar, cinnamon and  tsp of the vanilla paste. Arrange the pineapple in the buttery sugar mixture, tossing a little to coat. Try to fill all the gaps, so you cant see much of the base.",
              "equipment" : [

              ]
            },
            {
              "length" : {
                "unit" : "minutes",
                "number" : 3
              },
              "ingredients" : [

              ],
              "number" : 4,
              "step" : "In a mixing bowl, beat the caster sugar and remaining butter using an electric hand whisk for 2-3 mins until light and fluffy.",
              "equipment" : [
                {
                  "id" : 405907,
                  "image" : "mixing-bowl.jpg",
                  "name" : "mixing bowl"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 404661,
                  "image" : "whisk.png",
                  "name" : "whisk"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "ingredients" : [
                {
                  "id" : 1123,
                  "image" : "egg.png",
                  "name" : "egg"
                }
              ],
              "number" : 5,
              "step" : "Add the eggs and egg white, one at a time, and the remaining vanilla.",
              "equipment" : [

              ]
            },
            {
              "length" : {
                "unit" : "minutes",
                "number" : 1
              },
              "ingredients" : [
                {
                  "id" : 18371,
                  "image" : "white-powder.jpg",
                  "name" : "baking powder"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 20081,
                  "image" : "flour.png",
                  "name" : "all purpose flour"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1077,
                  "image" : "milk.png",
                  "name" : "milk"
                }
              ],
              "number" : 6,
              "step" : "Add the baking powder and a pinch of salt, then the flour and milk, beating until they are both incorporated. Beat for 1 min more until smooth.",
              "equipment" : [

              ]
            },
            {
              "ingredients" : [
                {
                  "id" : 9266,
                  "image" : "pineapple.jpg",
                  "name" : "pineapple"
                }
              ],
              "number" : 7,
              "step" : "Spoon the batter into the pan over the pineapple.",
              "equipment" : [
                {
                  "id" : 404645,
                  "image" : "pan.png",
                  "name" : "frying pan"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "length" : {
                "unit" : "minutes",
                "number" : 5
              },
              "ingredients" : [

              ],
              "number" : 8,
              "step" : "Bake for 1 hr, covering with foil if it starts to brown. Leave to rest for 5 mins, then turn out onto a platter and serve warm as a pudding, with crme frache, if you like. Alternatively, leave to cool completely in the tin and serve as a cake.",
              "equipment" : [
                {
                  "id" : 404765,
                  "image" : "aluminum-foil.png",
                  "name" : "aluminum foil"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "name" : ""
        }
      ],
      "spoonacularSourceUrl" : "https:\/\/spoonacular.com\/cinnamon-pineapple-upside-down-cake-212615",
      "vegetarian" : true,
      "gaps" : "no",
      "servings" : 8,
      "cookingMinutes" : 65,
      "title" : "Cinnamon pineapple upside-down cake",
      "id" : 212615,
      "image" : "https:\/\/spoonacular.com\/recipeImages\/212615-556x370.jpg",
      "glutenFree" : false,
      "dishTypes" : [
        "dessert"
      ],
      "lowFodmap" : false,
      "winePairing" : {
        "pairingText" : "Cream Sherry, Moscato d'Asti, and Port are my top picks for Cake. A common wine pairing rule is to make sure your wine is sweeter than your food. Delicate desserts go well with Moscato d'Asti, nutty desserts with cream sherry, and caramel or chocolate desserts pair well with port. The NV Johnson Estate Cream Sherry with a 5 out of 5 star rating seems like a good match. It costs about 19 dollars per bottle.",
        "pairedWines" : [
          "cream sherry",
          "moscato dasti",
          "port"
        ],
        "productMatches" : [
          {
            "link" : "https:\/\/www.amazon.com\/Johnson-Estate-Cream-Sherry-750\/dp\/B00D3GQSRW?tag=spoonacular-20",
            "score" : 0.85714285714285721,
            "id" : 430626,
            "price" : "$19.49",
            "title" : "NV Johnson Estate Cream Sherry",
            "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/spoonacular.com\/productImages\/430626-312x231.jpg",
            "averageRating" : 1,
            "description" : "Very aromatic with notes of hazelnut, vanilla, and a touch of oak followed by sweet raisins and a touch of yeast. Clean lasting finish. Good now but will reward those allow it to age\"\". A favorite pre-prandial beverage. Consider it with nuts before dinner as an aperitif, or after dinner with dessert, especially chocolates and fruit-based desserts. Also wonderful on cold afternoons, served with biscotti to dip in \"\"Italian-style\"\". \"",
            "ratingCount" : 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "dairyFree" : false,
      "occasions" : [

      ],
      "spoonacularScore" : 37,
      "pricePerServing" : 91.790000000000006,
      "readyInMinutes" : 85
    }
  ]
}
```

Recipe Class

```
struct Recipe {

    let id: Int
    let name: String

    // Recipes will only ever be instantiated in response to the server
    init(json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["id"].intValue
        self.name = json["title"].stringValue

    }

}
```

Parse code that's not working. It will return empty array.

```
let recipes: [Recipe] = json.arrayValue.map({ Recipe(json: $0) })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please **read** the JSON carefully.

The `recipes` array is in the (root) dictionary for key `recipes`

```
let recipes = json["recipes"].arrayValue.map{ Recipe(json: $0) }
```

It's highly recommended to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of the built-in `Codable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) library + [JSONExport](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport) for classes codeGen.

Comment: If you don't know how to *analyze* JSON the tool is irrelevant. And Codable is much more powerful than ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Codable protocol power.

I write playground example below.

```
import UIKit

// Models
struct Recipe: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String?
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let recipes: [Recipe]
}

// Test JSON
let jsonString = """
{
    "recipes": [
        {
            "id": 141892,
            "name": "Codable Recipe"
        },
        {
            "id": 908,
            "name": "JSON Recipe"
        }
    ]
}
"""

// Codable Test Drive
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print("recipes count: \(res.recipes.count)")
} catch {
    print("decode error: \(error)")
}
```

console output:
**recipes count: 2**